# Reduction from novel problem to Set Cover

Tags: reductions, polynomial-time-reductions, set-cover

i would like to perform a reduction for my novel problem to preferably the set cover problem, but i am a bit lost..

My problem can be described as follows:
Suppose you have given an binary word as input =101101…, an integer  and a set of smaller binary words $_1,_2,…,_$
with $length(w)$ is a strict divisor of $length(u)~ \forall~ w$.
Find $k$ of $n$ words ($k < n$) such that:

$\underbrace{_{_1},\dots,_{_1}}_{length(u)} \cup _{_2},\dots,_{_2} \cup 
\dots \cup _{_k},\dots,_{_k} = u$

if you extend the words $w$ to the length of $u$ (which is possible due to the chosen lengths of the $w$'s), the union over all $k$ of the $n$ words results in $u$.

(*It seems to me that this problem should be reducible to the set cover problem but i am unsure about the universe construction and have not that much experience in reducing problems.*)
Update: As Steven and Pal pointed out, the reduction needs to be in the other way, from Set Cover to my problem.

Any help or thought is welcome.

Comment: (The decision version of) your problem $A$ is definitely reducible to set-cover since $A \in\mathsf{NP}$ (a certificate is the ordered list  $1_1,\dots,1_k$) and set-cover is NP-complete. You can always get a reduction by writing down a non-deterministic Turing machine for $A$, using Cook's reduction to SAT, and then a (chain of) reductions from SAT to set-cover (for example there are standard reductions from SAT to 3-SAT and from 3-SAT to vertex cover, which is a special case of set-cover). Of course this is a rather ugly "brute-force" approach, Maybe somebody can provide a direct reduction.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, is there another way to prove the NP hardness without a reduction? I just thought this would be the most straight forward

Comment: The point Steven is making is that the reduction should go the other way, ie, you need to reduce from Set Cover to yours.

Comment: OMG, you are right, i have been looking on this for too long..

Comment: Is it enough to say that for a set $U$ i create the string $u$ by setting it to 1 at position $i$ iff $i \in U$ and create the words the same way for each subset?